# Multi database link and mix and match email alert

Tags: database

I have a site witch is a large database of people that have different knowledge in different domain... think about teaching (match, french, science etc...)

On the site there is a page where you can search people base on different request, think of distance from home, grade, sex

Now, i like to add a page where people that are looking for mentor will fill a request, and when a tutor in his area of search will match request, a email will be send to this researcher. Because i know for sure, that when in jnuary you look for a math teacher for you 10 year old son, and you find none, you WONT go again in febuary, march... and on and on just to see, maybe there is one now, you what to be inform when the tutor will get into database automaticly (more or less like www.jobboom.com)

So the question, what CMS i need to be able to do that ?, wordpress, drupal or something custom made?

-
maybe i can add... how can i make a cron job that will get all the request person in the database to run a search in all the giver job... and then send email upon result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use gravity form... it make interaction with data easy... i have found type and view : http://wp-types.com/features/ that look nice too